# Session HTTP - Spring and Angular 2

Tags: java, spring, angular, session, spring-boot

I have a problem adding an authentication feature to my spring boot application.
I have implemented the session pattern as below.

AdminSession.java

```
@Component
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class AdminSession {
private final String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
private Admin admin;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public Admin getAdmin() {
    return admin;
}

public void setAdmin(Admin admin) {
    this.admin = admin;
}
}
```

AdminController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/admin")
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class AdminController extends RestAbstractController<Admin, AdminService>{
@Autowired
private AdminService adminService;
@Autowired
private AdminSession adminSession;


@RequestMapping(value="/auth",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Admin> auth(
@RequestParam("pseudo") String pseudo, 
@RequestParam("password") String password,
){
Admin a = this.adminService.auth(pseudo, password);
if(a instanceof Admin) {
this.adminSession.setAdmin(a);
System.out.println("[DEBUG] Login "+this.adminSession.getAdmin());
this.displaySessionInfo();
}else System.err.println("[ERROR] a is not Admin instance");
return new ResponseEntity<Admin>(a,HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}

public Admin add(@RequestBody Admin admin){
if(!this.adminService.exist(admin.getPseudo())){
return super.add(admin);
}else return new Admin();

}

@RequestMapping("/isAuth")
public Admin isAuth(){

this.displaySessionInfo();
return this.adminSession.getAdmin();

}

private void displaySessionInfo(){
System.out.println("[DEBUG] Session info : "+this.adminSession.getId()+" "+this.adminSession.getAdmin()+" "+this.adminSession.toString());
}


}
```

The problem is that when I try to connect to the Angular side, Spring saves the user correctly in the session. But when I try to access the URL '/ admin / isAuth' after logging in, the session is not the same.

console LOG

```
2017-05-03 19:08:52.258  INFO 756 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 124 ms
# FIRST LOGIN
[DEBUG] Client connexion : 127.0.0.1 on /admin/auth
[DEBUG] Login root 
[DEBUG] Session info : 31e7a837-7b0e-4bcc-83a2-b5297a76d2e0 root fr.-----.session.AdminSession@6039cb34
# LOGIN SUCCESSFUL
# CHECK IS LOGIN
[DEBUG] Client connexion : 127.0.0.1 on /admin/isAuth
[DEBUG] Session info : f83ba190-0faa-480b-be1d-4b2745d4a168 null fr.-----.session.AdminSession@6052863f
```

Side Angular 2

Admin.service.ts

```
auth(pseudo:string,password:string):Observable<Admin>{
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post(this.provider.getURL()+"/admin/auth","pseudo="+pseudo+"&password="+password,options)
.map(this.extractData);
}
```

Login.component.ts

```
submit(){
    this.process=true;
    this.adminService.auth(this.pseudo,this.password).subscribe(t=>{
      this.adminService.isAuth();
      this.process=false;
      this.adminService.isAuthentified = true;
      this.provider.tokenSession = t;
      this.adminService.isAuth().subscribe(t=>console.log("Test login"));
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    },err=>console.error(err));
  }
```

Why I lost my http session ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Did you test it with browser or other HTTP client first?

Comment: I test with the same http browser, the same onglet, different, ...

Comment: Can you show me how you inject this.adminService?

Comment: I have add the code juste below.

Comment: Everything looks normal. Need to start with elementary diagnosing. How about use http.get to send several test requests against a normal API. Then check how session behaves.

Comment: The problem is well on the angular side. It does not keep the same session between two queries.

Answer (score 1):

I have identified the problem. I'ts side Angular 2.
For eatch request, the headers need 'withCredentials';

```
export class MyService {
  private httpGetOptions : RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ withCredentials: true });

  getSomeone (): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url,this.httpGetOptions);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AdminService.java

```
@Service
public class AdminService extends RestAbstractService<Admin, AdminRepository>{

    @Autowired
    private AdminRepository adminRepository;

    public Admin auth(String pseudo, String password, AdminSession adminSession){
        Admin a = this.adminRepository.findAdminByPseudo(pseudo);
        if(a instanceof Admin)
            if(a.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                adminSession.setAdmin(a);
                a.setPassword(null);
                return a;
            }
            else return null;
        else if(pseudo.equals("root") & Admin.root.getPassword().equals(password))
            return Admin.root;
        else return null;
    }

    public boolean exist(String pseudo){
        return this.adminRepository.findAdminByPseudo(pseudo) instanceof Admin;
    }

    public boolean isAuth(AdminSession adminSession){
        return adminSession.getAdmin() instanceof Admin;
    }


    public void logout(AdminSession adminSession){
        adminSession.setAdmin(null);
    }
}
```

Admin.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminService {
  isAuthentified:boolean;
  constructor(private provider :ProviderService, private http:Http) { }

  auth(pseudo:string,password:string):Observable<Admin>{
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.provider.getURL()+"/admin/auth","pseudo="+pseudo+"&password="+password,options)
      .map(this.extractData);
  }

  isAuth():Observable<boolean>{    
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json;', 'token': this.provider.tokenSession.token});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get(this.provider.getURL()+"/admin/isAuth",)
        .map(this.extractBoolean);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body;
  }

  private extractBoolean(res:Response){
    this.isAuthentified = res.text() === 'true';
    return this.isAuthentified;
  }


  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

}
```

In the "providerService" I have juste IP access to web service Spring.